# Populating a drop-down list in Appended Table Row

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a table in which rows can be added dynamically when a button is clicked. In each dynamic row, there are text fields and a drop-down list. The drop-down is populated from the database using jquery and a function in the model

**Script**

```
$('td #add_fields').click(function(){
item_count++;
 var url = baseURL+'interfaces/population';
$.ajax({           
   type: "GET",
   url: url,                          
   data:'',                        
   dataType: 'json',                  
   success: function(res){
   $('#item_body').append('<tr id="item_row">'+
     '<th>'+item_count+'</th>'+
     '<td>'+
     '<select class="form-control" id="item_name" name="item_name" style=" width:150px;">'+
     '<option value="none" selected="" disabled="">Select Item</option>');
        for(i in res) 
   $('#item_body').append('<option value="">'+res[i].item_name+'</option>');
   $('#item_body').append('</select>'+
       '</td>'+
       '<td><input type="text" name="qty_unit" id="qty_unit" class="form-control"></td>'+
       '<td><input type="text" name="price_p_u"  id="price_p_u" class="form-control"></td>'+
       '<td>'+
       '</td>'+
       '<td><input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" class="form-control"></td>'+
       '<td><input type="text" name="total_price" id="total_price" class="form-control"></td>'+
       '<td><input type="button" name="" class="btn btn-danger remove_fields" value="X" ></td>'+
       '</tr>');
     } 
 }); });
```

**Model**

```
public function get_item_data_app(){
$this->db->order_by('item_name');
$query=$this->db->get('stock');
$result=$query->result_array();
return $result;
}
```

I am able to get the data to populate the drop-down the list, however, it is not displaying in the drop-down list.

**Image1**
[image]

---

**Image2**
[image]

From the image1, the drop-down list data is not displaying in the drop-down list but on a different row and I don't get why it is doing so. But it would like it to display just like it is seen in image2 whenever the button is clicked.

Comment: your logic is wrong..in for loop it append only "<options></option></select>".... not append <select>

Comment: Manish I don't get u.. can you please explain further

Comment: you are giving the same id to every <tr>, <select> and <td> tags. and if you are appending the same tr on every button click event then it would be better to make an ajax call on page load and store it in a variable. In that way, you don't have to fetch the records from model every time. Just append that variable on button click.

Comment: @Rishi.. naa I'm populating the drop-down from the database.. however upon button click the populated data isn't showing in the drop-down.. its showing on a row beneath the row the select tag is

Comment: So I want it to be like image2 when the button is clicked such that all textfields and the populated drop-down  will be on a row..

Comment: <tr id="item_row">
<select class="form-control" id="item_name"...>
<input type="text" name="qty_unit" id="qty_unit"..>
<input type="text" name="price_p_u"  id="price_p_u"..>
 I am saying that you are giving the same id to all rows elements .. try giving different ids to each row

Comment: Ooh ok... I get u now

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
        your city :-
                <tr>

                  <select id="state" onchange="getCity()" >
                    <option value="na"  >Select State</option>
                      <?php
                       if (isset($state)) {
                        foreach ($state as $s) {                                            
                         echo '<option value="' . $s->id . '">' . $s->loc. '</option>';
                        }                                      
                      }  ?>
                 </select>
```

SCRIPT

```
    function getCity(){

    var state=$('#state').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>pms1/getCity/"+state, 
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(result){
            $('#city').html('<option>SELECT</option>');
           $.each( result, function( key, value ) {

              $('#city').append('<option value='+key+'>'+value+'</option>');
            });  
    }});

 }
```

This works on Onchange(), what you might be doing wrong must be HTML part.

Comment: if you find it helpful than an upvote will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Like Bilal and Rishi suggested,the issue was the html part.In the append function,the looping `option` had to be appended to the `select` and also set dynamic the ids' for the looping `option`created on `button click`

```
$('td #add_fields').click(function(){
item_count++;
 var url = baseURL+'interfaces/population';
$.ajax({           
        type: "GET",
        url: url,                           
        data:'',
        dataType: 'json',       
        success: function(res){
        $('#item_body').append('<tr id="item_row_add'+item_count+'">'+
        '<th>'+item_count+'</th>'+
        '<td>'+
        '<select class="form-control" id="item_name" name="item_name" style=" width:150px;">'+
        '<option value="none" selected="" disabled="">Select Item</option>');
         for(i in res){ 
        $('#item_row_add'+item_count+' select').append('<option value="'+res[i].id+'">'+res[i].item_name+'</option>');}
        $('#item_row_add'+item_count+'').append('</select>'+
        '</td>'+
        '<td><input type="text" name="qty_unit" id="qty_unit" class="form-control"></td>'+
        '<td><input type="text" name="price_p_u"  id="price_p_u" class="form-control"></td>'+
        '<td>'+
        '<select name="unit-type" id="unit-type" class="form-control" style=" width:90px;">'+
        '<option value="Unit">Unit</option>'+
        '<option value="Sub-Unit">Sub-Unit</option>'+
        '<option>Unit&Sub</option>'+
        '</select>'+
        '</td>'+
        '<td><input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" class="form-control"></td>'+
        '<td><input type="text" name="total_price" id="total_price" class="form-control"></td>'+
        '<td><input type="button" name="" class="btn btn-danger remove_fields" value="X" ></td>'+
        '</tr>');
            } 
 }); });
```